How can I re-generate an MD5 hash for an XML section?
I have the following XML code snippet:
<DeviceDataSection SectionType="1" Version="1" DataLength="32" SectionLength="64" MD5="42a0ecc7e8d43fdb6a31901826b534bf">
    <PartType>0</PartType>
    <PartNumber>587</PartNumber>
    <RevisionNumber>00</RevisionNumber>
    <SequenceNumber>0</SequenceNumber>
    <CageCode>3PVS5</CageCode>
    <FriendlyName>30XMK2</FriendlyName>
    <GrossWeight>521</GrossWeight>
    <ExpectedPowerDraw>7.5</ExpectedPowerDraw>
</DeviceDataSection>

but the MD5 checksum is incorrect, because one or more of the fields were changed. How can I re-generate the correct MD5 for just this section?

There's no one standardized way to do this. There are standards (like https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n11/) that can support an implementation by ensuring that there's only exactly one canonical bytestream that a given chunk of XML serializes to, but whether they'll actually work for your cases depend on whether the specific software that parses this file was built to follow that standard; if you don't specify what that software is, the question isn't answerable.

(Among the software-specific design decisions: What happens to the attribute storing the hash itself when getting ready to recalculate the hash for the section? Maybe that one attribute is removed; maybe its value is replaced with an empty string; maybe its value is replaced with all 0s; maybe the hash is only over the contained elements and not the wrapping outer element -- again, there's no one canonical set of answers here that every implementation follows, you need to know what the people writing the software for parsing/generating the specific format at hand decided).
